# Save imagepng to MySQL database

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a script that creates an image and calls `imagepng` to output it to the browser.
Instead, I would like to save it to a MySQL database (as a blob).
I know how to read a file into a prepared statement

```
while ($data = fread($fp, 1024)) {
    $size += strlen($data);
    $stmt->send_long_data(0, $data);
}
```

The problem is that I don't want to have `imagepng` write to a file just so I can read it back into the database.
Is there an easy way to do that?

**UPDATE:**
Here is how I tried to use output buffering:

```
ob_start();
imagepng($dst_r,null);
$img = ob_get_clean();

$db = Database::getInstance(); // Singleton on MySQLi
$s = $db->prepare("UPDATE " . $db->getTableName("Users") . " SET `Picture` = ? WHERE `UserID` = ?" );
$s->bind_param('bi', $img, $_POST['UserID']);
$s->send_long_data(0, $img);
$s->execute();
```

The database is not updated and there are no errors.

Comment: I guess ob_get_clean() is a tipo? It should be ob_end_clean().

Comment: @haltabush No, `ob_get_clean()` does the work of `ob_get_contents()` and `ob_end_clean()` in a single call. http://php.net/ob_get_clean

Comment: Oh. Good to know :) I written an update to my answer, does it works now?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From what I've just read in [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php), you can probably do that using a mix of [ob_start()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php), [ob_get_contents](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-contents.php) & [ob_end_clean()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-clean.php).

By a mix, I mean that:

```
ob_start();
imagepng($image);
$imageContent = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

If I were you, I would save it in a temporary file, but do as you wish :)

---

Edit: 
I think you also have a problem with the management of your DB. Here is what *might* works

```
//include here the thing to get $imageContent

$db = Database::getInstance(); // Singleton on MySQLi
$s = $db->prepare("UPDATE " . $db->getTableName("Users") . " SET `Picture` = ? WHERE `UserID` = ?" );
$null = NULL;
$s->bind_param('bi', $null, $_POST['UserID']);
$byteToSend = 1024;//this should equals the max_allowed_packet variable in your mysql config (usually in my.cnf config file)
$i=0;
while ($contentToSend = substr($imageContent, $i, $byteToSend)) {
    $s->send_long_data(0, $contentToSend);
    $i+=$byteToSend;
}
```

Comment: Using output buffering is perfectly fine. No need for temporary files.

Comment: I just hope he doesn't already use it at the beginning of the request. I don't know how we can get only a part of the buffer, and avoid to render it to the browser.

Comment: The output buffers are saved in a stack. Each time you `ob_start()`, all previous output will be saved and can be accessed again after calling `ob_end_*`. If he implements your example without any output, that should not go into the image, he will be fine. :-)

Comment: So if he has used ob_start() before, it might be annoying... But it still shouldn't be a big deal, he would only have to use
    `$alreadyInBuffer = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean(); 
    //the png stuff;
    echo $alreadyInBuffer;`.

Thank you

Comment: Nono, I meant that if you have something in the output buffer and call `ob_start()` again, a new empty buffer will be put on top of the stack. you can now write the image in this buffer, get it's contents with `ob_get_contents()`. remove it from the stack without outputting it with `ob_end_clean()`. after this the previous output buffer will be the top buffer again. you can nest this arbitrary times without each output buffer affacting one another.

Comment: @haltabush I have several layers of output buffering already because the framework I am using requires it. (Don't ask why.) It does work pretty well.

Comment: Your solution looked correct and I could not figure out why it still was not working. I finally turned on the SQL Query log and I discovered that `$_POST['UserID']` was not being set properly. That bug is now fixed. Now that I have accepted your answer, I will go back to banging my head against the wall. ;-)