# mysqli send_long_data fails

Tags: php, mysqli

I thought when I need to insert more than `max_allowed_packet`-sized BLOBs to the database via mysqli, I can make use of `send_long_data`. This seems to work for everyone (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9864298/2436555) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1316691/2436555) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4846674/2436555)). Here's a (not) working minimal example:

```
<?php
   # Establishing connection
   $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'database');
   $db->query('SET CHARACTER SET "utf8"');
   # Get max value
   $res = $db->query('SHOW VARIABLES WHERE `Variable_name` = "max_allowed_packet"');
   $max = (int)$res->fetch_assoc()['Value'];
   $res->free();
   # Prepare
   $content = file_get_contents('C:\\file.png');
   $stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE `table` SET `field` = ? WHERE `id` = ?');
   $null = null;
   $id   = 1;
   $stmt->bind_param('bi', $null, $id);
   # send_long_data
   $m = $max -8;
   $p = -$m;
   $l = strlen($content) + $p;
   while($p < $l)
      $stmt->send_long_data(0, substr($content, $p += $m, $m));
   if(!$stmt->execute())
      echo "{$db->errno}: {$db->error}";
   # finalize
   $stmt->close();
   $db->close();
?>
```

This works perfectly well if the package size is smaller than `max_packet_size`. If not, there are several problems:

- If I simply set `$m` to `$max`, it won't work. The error message is `2006: MySQL server has gone away`; before this, a warning is given: `Warning: Error while sending STMT_SEND_LONG_DATA packet. ... on line 20` (20 is `$stmt->send_long_data`)
- So I have to subtract at least a value of 8 from this `max_packet_size`. Why 8? Is it dependent on something? Why not simply `max_packet_size`?
- But ok, I subtract 8. Then it's the following error: `1105: Parameter of prepared statement which is set through mysql_send_long_data() is longer than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes`
- `substr` definitely returns the number of bytes, as `mbstring.func_overload = 0`.
- Transferring the image works if I do not use the while loop - but then of course a part of the image is not transferred. I thought `send_long_data` is intended for exactly that purpose that you can transfer more than `max_packet_size` bytes!
- By the way: Why is the error message telling me something about `mysql_send_long_data` and not `mysqli_send_long_data`?
- I thought this could be an error of MySQL, so I updated from 5.5 to 5.6.11 (current); this did not fix anything.
- I am using PHP 5.4.12.
- The database field is of type `LONGBLOB` and definitely able to hold the data. If I increase `max_packet_size`, everything works. But I cannot rely on having access to manipulation of the server variables.

What can I do to transfer more than `max_packet_size` bytes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is simply no way to go around the max_packet_size (without modifying it).

See MySQL documentation:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/packet-too-large.html

> Both the client and the server have their own max_allowed_packet
>   variable, so if you want to handle big packets, you must increase this
>   variable both in the client and in the server.

Comment: OK, but what's the sense of `send_long_data`? If the data is not sent in multiple packets - which would allow me to bypass `max_packet_size` - I could simply bind the data as a string as well.
And the PHP docs says:
Allows to send parameter data to the server in pieces (or chunks), e.g. if the size of a blob exceeds the size of max_allowed_packet.

Comment: I cannot explain, why it's not working. I've read the docu and played with your code, you're right that this function should work for chunked data.

every call to send_long_data() returns "TRUE",but the execute() in the end fails and no data is send to the DB.

I've checked PHP bug database with no success, same for MySQL bug database.

This makes me think, that my first answer was correct - there is no way around the max_paket_size and you cannot transfer larger blobs (not even with chunking them)... OR its a bug in mysql.

Comment: I found an entry in both bug databases: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=53483 (-> libmysql error), referring to http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=26824, which states: `A minor problem, and to fix it cleanly we need a significant or incompatible change. Setting to "To be fixed later".` However, it seems to have worked in some MySQL/PHP versions, but there's no chance at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

**You need to modify it like this:**

```
SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet = 32 * 1048576; // 32 MB
```

**I think PHP caches the chunks** sent by `send_long_data()` and then tries to send the packet all in one strike. So chunking or sending in one strike, `send_long_data()` still depends on the `@@max_allowed_packet` MySQL variable defined size.

**Which, IMHO, is beyond weird.**